# Extracting information via Onenote sharing link

Tags: shell, onenote

I use a Onenote notebook at work stored inside the corporate OneDrive to keep track of my todos. I set up a (view-only) sharing link to provide outside access to the notebook. **Does the sharing link expose an API to extract information from the notebook?**. I just need the raw data in any human readable format, be it json or xml. I read about Onenote + OData which seems a fitting candidate, however, I was unable to find any information related to my problem.

My end goal is to extract my todos to display them somewhere else and I had the intention of creating a simple shell script to do just that. I cannot use Onenote API (which, confusingly, is now apparently referred to as Graph API?) as it requires a subscription for an application client ID which is way too much fuss for such a simple thing so all I'm left with is the sharing link.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that'd be a security breach, you need to be an authenticated user that has access permissions to the notebook (in the graph) in order to make a call.